# How to format dd/mm/yy to dd-mon-yyyy in altova stylevision

Tags: xpath, xslt-2.0, altova

I am new to [Altova Stylevision](http://www.altova.com/stylevision.html). I need to format the date from `dd/mm/yy` to `dd/Mon/yyyy`.

I have tried the options suggested in the Altova manual but it does not seem to recognize the format.

Comment: I see the closing request, but I don't think this is off-topic, as Altova is all about XSLT 2.0, which is a programming language and well-supported on this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is almost three weeks old, so maybe meanwhile you have found an answer, for instance by looking it up at page 781 of [XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0 Programmer's Reference](http://amzn.com/0470192747) by Michael Kay. Or perhaps [somewhere else on the web](http://www.sixtree.com.au/community/articles/formatting-dates-and-times-using-xslt-2.0-and-xpath/).

To achieve what you want in XSLT 2.0, we first need to convert your date-like string into international date-time notation. Luckily, we only need to care about the date-part, which should take the form `YYYY-MM-DD`.

After that, we "just" need to call `format-date` with the proper picture string:

```
<!-- first, convert your date into int'l date-notation with a regex -->
<xsl:variable 
    name="date" 
    select="replace('14/09/2014', '(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)', '$3-$2-$1')" />

<!-- then, use a properly formatted picture string to get the abbrev. month -->
<xsl:value-of 
    select="format-date(xs:date($date), '[D01]/[MNn,3-3]/[Y]')" />
```

The output with conforming processors like [Saxon](http://saxonica.com) or [Exselt](http://exselt.net) (didn't try [Altova](http://altova.com)) is this: `14/Sep/2014`.

The picture string works as follows (from that same book I quoted):

- `[xxxx]` is a variable marker
- `[D01]` formats the day-part as a two-digit day (leave out the zero if you don't want leading zeroes)
- `[MNn,3-3]` formats the month with `M` as case-word with `Nn` with a width of min three and max three with `3-3`.
- `[Y]` formats the year in the default format as a four-digit year.

If you need the full name of the month, remove the width-specifier. If you need some other output, [check out the table in the XPath 3.0 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#rules-for-datetime-formatting) for what you can use in the picture string.